# Why do I get this NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, reference

I'm learning C# and having a problem with passing a reference.

```
double tmpNewEntry = -1;

for (int k = 0; k < pl2.Length; k++)
{
    p.countWithStepActivation(ref tmpNewEntry);
    // Console.WriteLine("answer = {0} | t = {1} | tmpNewEntry = {2}", p.answer, p.theta, tmpNewEntry);
    pl2[k].changeEntry(k, tmpNewEntry);
}
```

Now when I uncomment `WriteLine()` I get the proper result for `tmpNewEntry` but in the next line:

```
pl2[k].changeEntry(k, tmpNewEntry);
```

I get a *NullReferenceException*. What am I missing?

Comment: Most likely it's because the kth element of `pl2` is null... Does this happen on every iteration? If not, what's the value of `k` when it throws?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line, and check at every step the values of `pl2[k]` and `tmpNewEntry`. Maybe you are assigning `null` to `tmpNewEntry` in the `countWithStepActivation` method?

Comment: I had wrong initialization. But i didn`t see it. I`m sitting on this for couple hourse so i`m tired. thank you for fast response and opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 2):

You problem is

```
pl2[k].changeEntry(....
```

Are you sure `pl2[k]` is not NULL be it an array or List element?

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `pl2[k]` before you get the error? I bet it's null.

My guess is that the `.changeEntry` reference doesn't make sense to c# because the object (`pl2[k]`) is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

double tmpNewEntry = -1;

```
for (int k = 0; k < pl2.Length; k++)
{
     p.countWithStepActivation(ref tmpNewEntry);
     // Console.WriteLine("answer = {0} | t = {1} | tmpNewEntry = {2}", p.answer, p.theta, tmpNewEntry);
     if(pl2[k] != null)
     {
         pl2[k].changeEntry(k, tmpNewEntry);
     }
}
```